# How to alert getJSON response in jQuery file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

How to check the response of getJSON function call in jQuery file. Which function do I have to edit?

Comment: You mentioned a different product in ever 4 lines of text and virtually zero ways to help you. Please give more indications on what is wrong.

Comment: **(1)** there's no such thing as a jquery file, unless you're talking about a javascript holding jquery. **(2)** We don't know what functions you're talking about. **(3)** You just can't "alert an object", alerts take a string message, and object needs to be converted to a string first. If you replace `getJSON` with `get` you get to see the raw response instead of JSON.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've to agree with the comments above — your question is more than vague! So I'm now only guessing if that's what you want:

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

You might have to required the JSON library for this to work:
http://www.json.org/js.html